# Youtube video upload library (google-api-services) provides a new port every-time (which cannot be authorised)

Tags: java, http, google-api, port, google-api-client

I am trying to upload a video on youtube using `NetHttpTransport.java` class (as defined in the [example created by google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert?apix=true)). The problem is that everytime I get a new port from `GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()`. So the *URL* that is making a hit changes on every call.

*For example*-
URL1 = http://localhost:57005/Callback
URL2 = http://localhost:57296/Callback

Google won't allow an unknown URL. I have registered several URL's but I am getting a new port everytime, so the URL changes on every call.
[image: Authorised URL's]

On each call I get this error:
[image: Authorization error]

My problem would be solved if I can get a static port.

Instead of,

```
final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

I need something like this:

```
final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = 8080;
```

Code that failed:

```
final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
```

is still giving a new port everytime.

Comment: Configure your app / ID to use a static port.  is the way to go.

Comment: @DaImTo : Please suggest if there is any subclass of NetHttpTransport that provides static port. Thanks.

Comment: What IDE are you using?